# Nuke away "Do not use this!" tags!

Tags: discussion, tags

I found [troubleshooting](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/troubleshooting) has a very interesting tag excerpt:

> Do not use! This is a very general tag - please use a more specific tag to describe your problem.

If the tag is "too general" then shouldn't exist at all. Be on the look out and retag away.

Comment: Who reviewed that wiki? Who wrote that tag? Why wasn't it deleted? If the tag gets created again then it should banned...

Comment: @Alvar you really want to know? http://askubuntu.com/posts/33342/revisions

Comment: Well @jrg why did you create that wiki tag?

Comment: @Alvar the problem isn't the tag wiki but the tag itself... why should we have a tag about "troubleshooting" when almost all the questions are about "troubleshooting"...

Comment: When is it good to have a tag about troubleshooting? Isn't it better to describe the problem instead of what we want to do about it?

Comment: Everyone upvote this then: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124504/moderators-should-be-able-to-remove-burninate-a-tag-themselves